# Live555 compile for iOS build error

Tags: ios, live555

I'm trying to compile Live555 for iOS.

I have done the following:

```
./genMakefiles iphoneos
make
```

I get the following build errors:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -I../UsageEnvironment/include -I../groupsock/include -I../liveMedia/include -I../BasicUsageEnvironment/include -I.  -DBSD=1 -O2 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_LEN=1 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fPIC -arch armv7 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -Wall testMP3Streamer.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -o testMP3Streamer -L. -arch armv7 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk testMP3Streamer.o ../liveMedia/libliveMedia.a ../groupsock/libgroupsock.a ../BasicUsageEnvironment/libBasicUsageEnvironment.a ../UsageEnvironment/libUsageEnvironment.a 
ld: in /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [testMP3Streamer] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried changing the linker options to this as well in the config.iphoneos:

```
LINK_OPTS =             -L. -arch armv7 --isysroot=$(SDK)
```

When I change the linker options I get the following errors:

```
cd testProgs ; make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -I../UsageEnvironment/include -I../groupsock/include -I../liveMedia/include -I../BasicUsageEnvironment/include -I.  -DBSD=1 -O2 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_LEN=1 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fPIC -arch armv7 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -Wall testMP3Streamer.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -o testMP3Streamer -L. -arch armv7 --isysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk testMP3Streamer.o ../liveMedia/libliveMedia.a ../groupsock/libgroupsock.a ../BasicUsageEnvironment/libBasicUsageEnvironment.a ../UsageEnvironment/libUsageEnvironment.a 
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/lib/crt1.o, missing required architecture armv7 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "start", referenced from:
     -u command line option
     (maybe you meant: RTPInterface::startNetworkReading(void (*)(void*, int)), MediaSink::startPlaying(MediaSource&, void (*)(void*), void*))
  "_exit", referenced from:
      play()    in testMP3Streamer.o
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _main in testMP3Streamer.o
      MP3FileSource::MP3FileSource(UsageEnvironment&, __sFILE*)in libliveMedia.a(MP3FileSource.o)
      MP3FileSource::MP3FileSource(UsageEnvironment&, __sFILE*)in libliveMedia.a(MP3FileSource.o)
      MP3FileSource::createNew(UsageEnvironment&, char const*)in libliveMedia.a(MP3FileSource.o)
      _Tables::getOurTables(UsageEnvironment&, unsigned char)in libliveMedia.a(Media.o)
      MediaLookupTable::remove(char const*)in libliveMedia.a(Media.o)
      MediaLookupTable::ourMedia(UsageEnvironment&)       in libliveMedia.a(Media.o)
      ...
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you share full config file `config.iphoneos` - got same problem but proposed fix not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change LINK_OPTS of config.iphoneos before running "genMakefiles iphoneos". It works for me on iOS 5.1 SDK and iOS 6 SDK beta.

```
LINK_OPTS =             -L. -arch armv7 --sysroot=$(SDK) -L$(SDK)/usr/lib/system
```

Answer (score 2):

I just change the compile.iphoneos :

```
IOS_VERSION =       5.1
LINK_OPTS =                 -L. .....
```

To

```
IOS_VERSION =       6.0
LINK_OPTS =             -L. -arch armv7 --sysroot=$(SDK) -L$(SDK)/usr/lib/system
```

And it successfully compiles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must modify `--isysroot` to `-isysroot`